# Intercepting method calls to my Java and Groovy code using Byte Buddy: Strange java.lang.VerifyError

Tags: java, bytecode, instrumentation, byte-buddy

I try to intercept calls to methods of classes from a mixed Java (8) and Groovy (2.4.5) project using Byte Buddy 0.7.1.

The idea is to create something like a little "generic logging flight recorder" for method calls and their arguments for classes in a specific package like `foo`.

I use a Byte Buddy `AgentBuilder` and my custom `LogInterceptor` to do this at application startup:

```
static {
  final Instrumentation inst = ByteBuddyAgent.install();
  new AgentBuilder.Default()
        .type(ElementMatchers.nameContainsIgnoreCase("foo")) // simplified
        .transform((builder, typeDescription) ->
                builder.method(ElementMatchers.any())
                        .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(LogInterceptor.class)
                           .andThen(SuperMethodCall.INSTANCE)))
        .installOn(inst);
}

public static class LogInterceptor {
  @RuntimeType
  public static void log(@Origin Method method, @AllArguments Object[] arg) throws Exception {
    // flightRecorder.log(...);
  }
}
```

The method interception works fine for all Java classes. And it works fine for all Groovy classes with a `@CompileStatic` annotation.

But it fails for classic (dynamic) Groovy classes with strange `java.lang.VerifyError`s like

```
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: foo/MyInterceptedClass$barMethod, method: <clinit> signature: ()V) Illegal type in constant pool

    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassLoaderForClassArtifacts.defineClassAndGetConstructor(ClassLoaderForClassArtifacts.java:83)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteGenerator.compileStaticMethod(CallSiteGenerator.java:246)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.createStaticMetaMethodSite(CachedMethod.java:288)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.createStaticMetaMethodSite(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:114)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.createStaticSite(MetaClassImpl.java:3385)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createCallStaticSite(CallSiteArray.java:77)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createCallSite(CallSiteArray.java:162)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)    
    ...
```

What's going on here? Does Byte Buddy support Groovy method interception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a reason unknown to me, Groovy generates classes of a class level 1.4 where certain byte code constructs that Byte Buddy generates are not legal. This generates a `VerifyError`. This is of course not a very constructive error message when working with Byte Buddy, which is why the class validator that Byte Buddy applies does now check for illegal use of *modern* concepts in Java byte code 1.4.

To overcome this limitation, Byte Buddy 0.7.2 (released today) includes a `ClassVisitorWrapper` which fixes the *modern* byte code to be represented by compatible, legacy intstructions when registering the added `TypeConstantAdjustment`. This adjustment is not perfect as, in case a class is missing, it will cause an `ClassNotFoundException` where the JLS normally requires a `NoClassDefFoundError`. If you can live with this limitation, it is save to use. The adjustment discovers by itself if it is required (Java 4 or older), so you can simply add it if you require it.

Comment: Interesting that Groovy 2.4.5 "still" creates byte code with class file version 48 (Java 1.4), since itself requires Java 6+ (Groovy 2.4.x). Java 6 introduced class file version 50. That's some extra work for byte code manipulation libraries like Byte Buddy! ;-)

Comment: I don't know about version 48, but it's a lot easier to generate version 49 classfiles compared to 50+ because StackMapTables aren't required. In practice, the JVM will accept version 50 without stack maps, but this isn't guaranteed by the standard. 49 is also the last version to allow jsr/ret.